Personal Domain Redirect to Several Aliased Hosts
I'm looking at attempting to redirect a personal domain to multiple different hosting providers. Say for instance I have a blog built with Jekyll deployed to both GitHub & GitLab Pages, and both services offer users the ability to use their own domains to make linking to the website cleaner.
In practice this means having a CNAME record under <blog.mydomain.com> that points to either GitHub or GitLab with the ability to add SSL certificates, plus some other DNS records and other things depending which provider is being used.
If I wanted to deploy to both and have my single <blog.mydomain.com> do a sort of primitive load balance between both services I think I would have to have no CNAMES and instead point my subdomain to reverse proxy using an A record and then that reverse proxy would handle the redirects and load balancing between both GitHub and GitLab.
Is this something that's possible? Would it still be able to preserve SSL functionality? Or am I completely off base with this idea and there's something fundamentally broken about what I'm trying accomplish?
I've got some experience working with NGINX, and want to get more familiar with Caddy.

What specific outcomes are you looking for by load balancing between GitHub Pages and GitLab Pages? GitHub Pages serves its content through Fastly CDN, so anything you post there is already being served up from 95 data centers distributed worldwide. Please edit your question to clarify your problem statement, goals and desired outcome, and it will be added to the queue for reopening. Thanks!

@MaximillianLaumeister  I think this close vote is unfair.  The question can be answered and does not need clarification.   Please consider reopening it.

Yes, you are on the right track, and this is definitely possible,    The question about SSL functionality is a bit tricky.   Effectively the reverse proxy acts as a man in the middle - so it would need certs so it can negotiate the connection with the client.    You would then have a second https session between the reverse proxy and the actual servers.      I've not done this with NGINX or Caddy, but I have done it with Apache (and maybe, a long time ago, with Squid) - but the principles are the same.

@davidgo Part of my reasoning for closing it was that it looks like an XY problem to me. For static sites, using a reverse proxy can only slow them down, because it's cheaper for a server to go to its own disk or memory than to go out to the network. If it's about keeping things in sync with a git repo, then a webhook or github action can be used - or if a reverse proxy is needed, it can be done with a single upstream host. Personally I believe the question could use some more clarification, but I respect your opinion so I've reopened it.

@MaximillianLaumeister thank you for reopening this post. And also for the link to the XY problem, that was basically the trap I fell into.

@davidgo - Awesome, good to know. I'll make an attempt at this then and see how far I get since it might be possible. I appreciate that there's likely no existing direct example of how to accomplish this with a reverse proxy/webserver.

@MaximillianLaumeister I didn't really go into detail about my problem because it's kinda of niche and thought it would raise more questions than answers so I went with a hypothetical that would be more understandable to more people. My specific problem has nothing to do with GitHub/GitLab pages but with a protocol called IPFS (think BitTorrent like static content distribution based on content hashes). IPFS content can be accessed through any number of public gateways over HTTP[S].
If I had a blog hosted on several public gateways how would I have my personal domain point to all of them?

IPFS public gateway docs: https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/ipfs-gateway/

If you're just trying to get your IPFS content visible via a custom domain in a reliable way, I highly recommend using a Cloudflare gateway with DNSLink. Cloudflare is likely to be the gold standard in terms of IPFS gateway reliability, and they do edge caching too, so there's already some load balancing built in. I understand that IPFS is a niche protocol so I get why you decided to leave that part out, but since IPFS is so unique, it's helpful IMO for solutions to this to be tailored to the specific nature of IPFS.

Here's a helpful tutorial on how to set your DNS record: How to leverage Cloudflare and IPFS distributed web to host a free high-availability site Edit: And another tutorial: How to Host a Website on IPFS using Piñata and Cloudflare

Thanks again @maximillianlaumeister . my personal hangup with cloudflare is that you have to use their name servers by adding your domain to a cloudflare account. I get this has to do with automating and smoothing the SSL certificate process, plus any other DNS nuances, but I just don't like the vendor lock in this creates. Plus with Pinata you can't pin IPNS records, just IPFS CIDs. So I'm looking to ultimately create a selfhosted solution that can subscribe to an offline IPNS record, as well as provide a  public gateway to that record. I've already done the IPNS part

For instance, at the moment but for any future readers these links will be broken, I have my IPNS _dnslink TXT record pointing to /ipns/....; with a CNAME pointing to blog-labadappt-com.ipns.labadappt.com. my nginx config isn't quite right cause manually going to that cname goes to the default NGINX landing page, but the custom subdomain works witout  SSL. The node that signed the IPNS record has been offline for a while and still resolves since the online gateway has subscribed to it using IPNS over pubsub.

On a related note, I just found this article stating that Cloudflare is sunsetting its IPFS gateway. Cloudflare’s public IPFS gateways and supporting Interplanetary Shipyard. Interesting that it it was buried so deeply that it took me so long to find. To answer your original question, DNS does not itself really support good failover between multiple domains, though I've found myself wanting it too (related post). Best of luck with this project.

Oh wow, I wasn't aware of any of that either. And I don't think the dweb.link gateway has the cname linking, TLS, or other things the cloudflare provider was offering. Cheers and thanks very much for sharing!
